# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED all.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: php, filenotfoundexception

I am using laravel 8.1 version unable to find this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED all.min.css:1
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED One more thing:
> I'm also not track where $activeTemplateTrue is initialized, Your help
> highly appreciate
> href="{{asset($activeTemplateTrue.'frontend/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css')}}

I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `@dd` directive of blade before the line containing `{{ asset($activeTemplateTrue . 'frontend/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css') }}` to show the content of `$activeTemplateTrue

I think the `$activeTemplateTrue` variable reference to directory prefix, but I didn't understand the "True" suffix of `$activeTemplate`. You need to check `$activeTemplateTrue` content.

If your project uses ***barryvdh/laravel-debugbar*** package, check `route` tab, and you can know the controller who renders the current view and see parameters shared in controller method, also you can see parameters shared to the current view in `views` tab.

[barryvdh/laravel-debugbar on route tabs with highlighted controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzJlx.png)